# SplitViewController with a Login View Controller as the root

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

So I've been researching on how to make a login view controller as the initial view controller instead of the splitview.

Some of the answers I've seen would recommend a modal view to be loaded? I'm not sure how that is set up.

eg.

[How to add a login view before a UISplitViewController iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607787/how-to-add-a-login-view-before-a-uisplitviewcontroller-ipad)

and

[How to implement SplitViewController on second level.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816670/how-to-implement-splitviewcontroller-on-second-level)

So do I add those on the loginviewcontroller class? Or where?

Any advice is welcome.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this by creating two storyboards: one with the (full-screen) login and one with the split-view.

To switch between them, I've added a custom protocol:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol RootViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)switchToStoryboard: (UIStoryboard *) storyboad animationDirectionOrNil: (NSString *)direction;

@end
```

The AppDelegate then implements this protocol:

```
-(void)switchToStoryboard:(id)storyboad animationDirectionOrNil:(NSString *)direction {
    UIViewController *newRoot=[storyboad instantiateInitialViewController];
    if ([newRoot respondsToSelector:@selector(setRootViewControllerDelegate:)]) {
        [newRoot setRootViewControllerDelegate:self];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController=newRoot;

    if(direction){
        CATransition* transition=[CATransition animation];
        transition.type=kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype=direction;
        [self.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"push_transition"];
    }
}
```

As you can see, it tries to set itself as the delegate again, so the other view-controller can switch back or to another storyboard. In order for this to work, you would have to subclass UISplitView:

**Header**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RootViewControllerDelegate.h"

@interface MySplitViewController : UISplitViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <RootViewControllerDelegate> rootViewControllerDelegate;

@end
```

**iMplementation**

```
#import "MySplitViewController.h"

@implementation MySplitViewController
@synthesize rootViewControllerDelegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for (UIViewController *viewController in self.viewControllers) {
        if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setRootViewControllerDelegate:)]) {
            [viewController setRootViewControllerDelegate:self.rootViewControllerDelegate];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

This simple implementation looks for child-view-controllers that accept a root-view-controller-delegate and hands it down. So when you want to add a "Show Login"-button to a certain (master- or detail-)view, just create your own UIViewController-subclass, add a `@property id<RootViewControllerDelegate> rootViewControllerDelegate` and associate an action like this with the button:

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *mainSB=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LoginStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    NSString *animationDirection=kCATransitionFromTop;
    UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation=[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (currentOrientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        animationDirection=kCATransitionFromBottom;
    }
    [self.rootViewControllerDelegate switchToStoryboard:mainSB animationDirectionOrNil:animationDirection];
}
```

Feel free to adjust everything to your needs.

Comment: thanks for the answer!! i have a question tho as im a little confused. so whenever i have a uiviewcontroller subclass, just add a property right? do i do this > @property(nonatomic,retain) id RootViewControllerDelegate ? is that correct? Also, do i understand this correctl, i will associate that loginButtonClicked if I want the login to show up? or is that for the class that will show the login view?

Comment: @gdubs: Yes, the `IBAction`-code goes to the UIViewController that owns the "Show Login"-button.
And obviously it then needs the `@property ... rootViewControllerDelegate`.  

I've edited the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

well here it is my friend. i created a ibaction in in btn and pushed the new view with modal option of the story board. them i plugged in the classes for the login view which also refers to constants that keeps the record strait. then after login is recognized i pushed a new view. bare in mind i was having the users create a password in their device and not importing it from the server. if you want to import it from the server it will be different.

here is the log in .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Constants.h"

@interface LogInViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) BOOL pinValidated;

@end
```

and here is the code for login .m

```
#import "LogInViewController.h"
#import "KeychainWrapper.h"

@interface LogInViewController ()

@end

@implementation LogInViewController

@synthesize pinValidated;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

// Helper method to congregate the Name and PIN fields for validation.
- (BOOL)credentialsValidated 
{
NSString *name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:USERNAME];
BOOL pin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:PIN_SAVED];
if (name && pin) {
    return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
}
}

- (void)presentAlertViewForPassword 
{

// 1
BOOL hasPin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:PIN_SAVED];

// 2
if (hasPin) {
    // 3
    NSString *user = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:USERNAME];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What is %@'s password?", user];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter Password" 
                                                    message:message  
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
    // 4
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput]; // Gives us the password    field
    alert.tag = kAlertTypePIN;
    // 5
    UITextField *pinField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    pinField.delegate = self;
    pinField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    pinField.tag = kTextFieldPIN;
    [alert show];
} else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Setup Credentials" 
                                                    message:@"Enter Your information!"  
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
    // 6
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
    alert.tag = kAlertTypeSetup;
    UITextField *nameField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    nameField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    nameField.placeholder = @"Name"; // Replace the standard placeholder text with   something more applicable
    nameField.delegate = self;
    nameField.tag = kTextFieldName;
    UITextField *passwordField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1]; // Capture the Password text field since there are 2 fields
    passwordField.delegate = self;
    passwordField.tag = kTextFieldPassword;
    [alert show];
}
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
if (alertView.tag == kAlertTypePIN) {
    if (buttonIndex == 1 && self.pinValidated) { // User selected "Done"
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ScoutSegue" sender:self];
        self.pinValidated = NO;
    } else { // User selected "Cancel"
        [self presentAlertViewForPassword];
    }
} else if (alertView.tag == kAlertTypeSetup) {
    if (buttonIndex == 1 && [self credentialsValidated]) { // User selected "Done"
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ScoutSegue" sender:self];
    } else { // User selected "Cancel"
        [self presentAlertViewForPassword];
    }
}
}


#pragma mark - Text Field + Alert View Methods
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
// 1
switch (textField.tag) {
    case kTextFieldPIN: // We go here if this is the 2nd+ time used (we've already set a    PIN at Setup).
        NSLog(@"User entered PIN to validate");
        if ([textField.text length] > 0) {
            // 2
            NSUInteger fieldHash = [textField.text hash]; // Get the hash of the entered PIN, minimize contact with the real password
            // 3
            if ([KeychainWrapper compareKeychainValueForMatchingPIN:fieldHash]) { // Compare them
                NSLog(@"** User Authenticated!!");
                self.pinValidated = YES;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"** Wrong Password :(");
                self.pinValidated = NO;
            }
        }
        break;
    case kTextFieldName: // 1st part of the Setup flow.
        NSLog(@"User entered name");
        if ([textField.text length] > 0) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:textField.text  forKey:USERNAME];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
        break;
    case kTextFieldPassword: // 2nd half of the Setup flow.
        NSLog(@"User entered PIN");
        if ([textField.text length] > 0) {
            NSUInteger fieldHash = [textField.text hash];
            // 4
            NSString *fieldString = [KeychainWrapper securedSHA256DigestHashForPIN:fieldHash];
            NSLog(@"** Password Hash - %@", fieldString);
            // Save PIN hash to the keychain (NEVER store the direct PIN)
            if ([KeychainWrapper createKeychainValue:fieldString forIdentifier:PIN_SAVED])        {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:PIN_SAVED];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                NSLog(@"** Key saved successfully to Keychain!!");
            }                
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.pinValidated = NO;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self presentAlertViewForPassword];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

here is the code for the constant

```
// Used for saving to NSUserDefaults that a PIN has been set, and is the unique identifier  for the Keychain.
#define PIN_SAVED @"hasSavedPIN"

// Used for saving the user's name to NSUserDefaults.
#define USERNAME @"username"

// Used to specify the application used in accessing the Keychain.
#define APP_NAME [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]  objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"]

// Used to help secure the PIN.
// Ideally, this is randomly generated, but to avoid the unnecessary complexity and overhead of storing the Salt separately, we will standardize on this key.
 // !!KEEP IT A SECRET!!
 #define SALT_HASH      @"FvTivqTqZXsgLLx1v3P8TGRyVHaSOB1pvfm02wvGadj7RLHV8GrfxaZ84oGA8RsKdNRpxdAojXYg9iAj"

// Typedefs just to make it a little easier to read in code.
typedef enum {
kAlertTypePIN = 0,
kAlertTypeSetup
} AlertTypes;

typedef enum {
kTextFieldPIN = 1,
kTextFieldName,
kTextFieldPassword
} TextFieldTypes;
```

here is the keychainwrapper

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Security/Security.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>

@interface KeychainWrapper : NSObject

// Generic exposed method to search the keychain for a given value. Limit one result per  search.
+ (NSData *)searchKeychainCopyMatchingIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

// Calls searchKeychainCopyMatchingIdentifier: and converts to a string value.
+ (NSString *)keychainStringFromMatchingIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

// Simple method to compare a passed in hash value with what is stored in the keychain.
// Optionally, we could adjust this method to take in the keychain key to look up the value.
+ (BOOL)compareKeychainValueForMatchingPIN:(NSUInteger)pinHash;

// Default initializer to store a value in the keychain.  
// Associated properties are handled for you - setting Data Protection Access, Company Identifer (to uniquely identify string, etc).
+ (BOOL)createKeychainValue:(NSString *)value forIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

// Updates a value in the keychain. If you try to set the value with createKeychainValue: and it already exists,
// this method is called instead to update the value in place.
+ (BOOL)updateKeychainValue:(NSString *)value forIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

// Delete a value in the keychain.
+ (void)deleteItemFromKeychainWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

// Generates an SHA256 (much more secure than MD5) hash.
+ (NSString *)securedSHA256DigestHashForPIN:(NSUInteger)pinHash;
+ (NSString*)computeSHA256DigestForString:(NSString*)input;

@end
```

and finally here is the code for the keychainwrapper .m

```
#import "KeychainWrapper.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation KeychainWrapper
// *** NOTE *** This class is ARC compliant - any references to CF classes must be paired  with a "__bridge" statement to 
// cast between Objective-C and Core Foundation Classes.  WWDC 2011 Video "Introduction to Automatic Reference Counting" explains this.
// *** END NOTE ***
 + (NSMutableDictionary *)setupSearchDirectoryForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {

// Setup dictionary to access keychain.
NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];  
// Specify we are using a password (rather than a certificate, internet password, etc).
[searchDictionary setObject:( id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:( id)kSecClass];
// Uniquely identify this keychain accessor.
[searchDictionary setObject:APP_NAME forKey:( id)kSecAttrService];

// Uniquely identify the account who will be accessing the keychain.
NSData *encodedIdentifier = [identifier dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[searchDictionary setObject:encodedIdentifier forKey:( id)kSecAttrGeneric];
[searchDictionary setObject:encodedIdentifier forKey:( id)kSecAttrAccount];

return searchDictionary; 
}

+ (NSData *)searchKeychainCopyMatchingIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier 
{

NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [self  setupSearchDirectoryForIdentifier:identifier];
// Limit search results to one.
[searchDictionary setObject:( id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:( id)kSecMatchLimit];

// Specify we want NSData/CFData returned.
[searchDictionary setObject:( id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:( id)kSecReturnData];

// Search.
NSData *result = nil;   
CFTypeRef foundDict = NULL;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(( CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, &foundDict);

if (status == noErr) {
    result = ( NSData *)foundDict;
} else {
    result = nil;
}

return result;
}

+ (NSString *)keychainStringFromMatchingIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier 
{
NSData *valueData = [self searchKeychainCopyMatchingIdentifier:identifier];
if (valueData) {
    NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:valueData
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return value;
} else {
    return nil;
}
}

+ (BOOL)createKeychainValue:(NSString *)value forIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier 
{

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [self setupSearchDirectoryForIdentifier:identifier];
NSData *valueData = [value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[dictionary setObject:valueData forKey:( id)kSecValueData];

// Protect the keychain entry so it's only valid when the device is unlocked.
[dictionary setObject:( id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked forKey:( id)kSecAttrAccessible];

// Add.
OSStatus status = SecItemAdd(( CFDictionaryRef)dictionary, NULL);

// If the addition was successful, return. Otherwise, attempt to update existing key or quit (return NO).
if (status == errSecSuccess) {
    return YES;
} else if (status == errSecDuplicateItem){
    return [self updateKeychainValue:value forIdentifier:identifier];
} else {
    return NO;
}
}

+ (BOOL)updateKeychainValue:(NSString *)value forIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier 
{

NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [self  setupSearchDirectoryForIdentifier:identifier];
NSMutableDictionary *updateDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSData *valueData = [value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[updateDictionary setObject:valueData forKey:( id)kSecValueData];

// Update.
OSStatus status = SecItemUpdate(( CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary,
                                ( CFDictionaryRef)updateDictionary);

if (status == errSecSuccess) {
    return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
}
}

+ (void)deleteItemFromKeychainWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier 
{
NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [self setupSearchDirectoryForIdentifier:identifier];
CFDictionaryRef dictionary = ( CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary;

//Delete.
SecItemDelete(dictionary);
}


+ (BOOL)compareKeychainValueForMatchingPIN:(NSUInteger)pinHash 
{

if ([[self keychainStringFromMatchingIdentifier:PIN_SAVED] isEqualToString:[self securedSHA256DigestHashForPIN:pinHash]]) {
    return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
}    
}

// This is where most of the magic happens (the rest of it happens in computeSHA256DigestForString: method below).
// Here we are passing in the hash of the PIN that the user entered so that we can avoid manually handling the PIN itself.
// Then we are extracting the username that the user supplied during setup, so that we can add another unique element to the hash.
// From there, we mash the user name, the passed-in PIN hash, and the secret key (from ChristmasConstants.h) together to create 
// one long, unique string.
// Then we send that entire hash mashup into the SHA256 method below to create a "Digital Digest," which is considered
// a one-way encryption algorithm. "One-way" means that it can never be reverse-engineered, only brute-force attacked.
// The algorthim we are using is Hash = SHA256(Name + Salt + (Hash(PIN))). This is called   "Digest Authentication."
+ (NSString *)securedSHA256DigestHashForPIN:(NSUInteger)pinHash 
{
// 1
NSString *name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:USERNAME];
name = [name stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// 2
NSString *computedHashString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i%@", name, pinHash, SALT_HASH];
// 3
NSString *finalHash = [self computeSHA256DigestForString:computedHashString];
NSLog(@"** Computed hash: %@ for SHA256 Digest: %@", computedHashString, finalHash);
return finalHash;
}

// This is where the rest of the magic happens.
// Here we are taking in our string hash, placing that inside of a C Char Array, then parsing it through the SHA256 encryption method.
+ (NSString*)computeSHA256DigestForString:(NSString*)input 
 {

const char *cstr = [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:input.length];
uint8_t digest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

// This is an iOS5-specific method.
// It takes in the data, how much data, and then output format, which in this case is an int array.
CC_SHA256(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

// Setup our Objective-C output.
NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH *  2];

// Parse through the CC_SHA256 results (stored inside of digest[]).
for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
}

return output;
}

@end
```

this is the blueprint for creating a login view before any other view weather it be view controller or any other view such as tab bar or so. take a good look at this set of codes and modify them as you please. hope this helps you my friend. the codes are there all you have to do is study them and modify them to what you want. happy coding.